# Make $elemMatch return all the related data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a code which runs perfectly fine BUT I am looking for a better solution than my code.

```
let parkings = await Parking.find(
      {
        "location.city": req.body.city,
      },
      {
        availability: {
          $elemMatch: { day: dayjs(req.body.date).format("dddd") },
        },
        totalSpots: 1,
        contactInfo: 1,
        about: 1,
        parkingImage: 1,
        coordinates: 1,
        parkingtype: 1,
        isFeePaid: 1,
        status: 1,
        parkingInfo: 1,
        parkingZone: 1,
        specialEvents: 1,
        price: 1,
        _id: -1,
      }
    );
```

$elemMatch returns only one particular field which is mentioned (ie. day). If I want to see other related details for that data I have to explicitly mention that field.

If I remove the part `contactInfo: 1 to _id: -1` Then I am seeing this result.

```
{
    "parkingList": [
        {
            "_id": "62e11ab3079daa939290fa07",
            "totalSpots": 127,
            "availability": [
                {
                    "day": "Friday",
                    "startTime": "08:00",
                    "endTime": "16:00",
                    "_id": "62e11ab3079daa939290fa0e"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "availableSpots": 125
}
```

see, there is no other data like contactInfo, parkingImage, about etc.

And if I include the above code then I am getting this result.

```
{
    "parkingList": [
        {
            "contactInfo": {
                "name": "Claudia Shields",
                "phoneNumber": 8904672101
            },
            "coordinates": {
                "lng": 34.048954,
                "lat": 10.299556
            },
            "_id": "62e11ab3079daa939290fa07",
            "about": "Nisi occaecat ipsum",
            "parkingImage": [],
            "price": 5,
            "parkingInfo": [
                {
                    "parkingName": "Fountain Avenue",
                    "default": [],
                    "_id": "62e11ab3079daa939290fa0f"
                }
            ],
            "totalSpots": 127,
            "status": "active",
            "isFeePaid": false,
            "parkingZone": [],
            "specialEvents": [],
            "availability": [
                {
                    "day": "Friday",
                    "startTime": "08:00",
                    "endTime": "16:00",
                    "_id": "62e11ab3079daa939290fa0e"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "availableSpots": 125
}
```

Is there any better solution then this?

Comment: can you show an example document, and what you are getting in the result? and your expected result document.

Comment: @turivishal question edited.